# How to create a sandboxed RSpec environment?

Tags: ruby, rspec, jruby, sandbox

Essentially, I want to create a program that will run some untrusted code that defines some method or class, and then run an untrusted rspec spec against it.

I've looked into sandboxing Ruby a bit, and [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6XxCOYco3Eg) from rubyconf was particularly helpful. After looking at several solutions, the two that appear to be the most helpful are [rubycop](https://github.com/envylabs/RubyCop), which essentially does static analysis on the code, and the [jruby sandbox](https://github.com/omghax/jruby-sandbox) (both covered in above video). My instinct tells me that the jruby sandbox is probably safer, but I could well be wrong.

Here's a completely unsafe example of what I want to do:

```
code = <<-RUBY
class Person
  def hey
    "hey!"
  end
end
RUBY

spec = <<-RUBY
describe Person do
  let(:person) { Person.new }

  it "says hey" do
    person.hey.should == "hey!"
  end
end
RUBY

# code and spec will be from user input (unsafe)

eval code
require 'rspec/autorun'
eval spec
```

Which all works fine, but the code obviously needs to be sandboxed. It will be a matter of minutes before some genius submits `system("rm -rf /*")`, `fork while fork` or something equally dangerous.

I made various attempts with the jruby sandbox...

```
sand = Sandbox::Safe.new
sand.eval("require 'rspec/autorun'")
sand.activate! # lock it down
sand.eval code
puts sand.eval spec
```

That code throws this exception:

```
Sandbox::SandboxException: NoMethodError: undefined method `require' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x7c3cfaab>
```

This is because RSpec tries to require some stuff after the sandbox has been locked down.

So, I tried to force RSpec to require stuff before the sandbox gets locked down by calling an empty `describe`:

```
sand = Sandbox::Safe.new
sand.eval("require 'rspec/autorun'")
sand.eval("describe("") { }")
sand.activate! # lock it down
sand.eval code
sand.eval spec
```

And I get this:

```
Sandbox::SandboxException: NameError: uninitialized constant RSpec
```

Which basically means that `RSpec` doesn't exist in the sandbox. Which is odd, considering `sand.eval("require 'rspec/autorun'")` returns true, and that the earlier example actually worked (RSpec's autoloader started to run).

It may be a problem with gems and this particular sandbox though. The sandbox object actually supports a method `#require`, which is essentially bound to `Kernel.require`, and therefore can't load gems.

It's starting to look like using this sandbox just might not really be possible with rspec. The main problem is trying to actually load it into the sandbox. I even tried something like this:

```
require 'rspec'
sand.ref(RSpec) # open access to local rspec
```

But it wasn't having any of it.

So, my question is two-fold:

- Does anyone have any bright ideas on how to get this to work with the jruby sandbox?
- If not, how secure is [rubycop](https://github.com/envylabs/RubyCop)? Apparently [codeschool](http://codeschool.com) use it, so it must be pretty well tested... it would be nice to be able to use ruby 1.9 instead of jruby as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the sand box environment isn't loading the bundle/gemset. RVM could be at fault here if you are using a gemset or something.

One might try loading the Bundle again once sand boxed.

I would look at ruby taint modes

```
$SAFE   The security level
0 --> No checks are performed on externally supplied (tainted) data. (default)
1 --> Potentially dangerous operations using tainted data are forbidden.
2 --> Potentially dangerous operations on processes and files are forbidden.
3 --> All newly created objects are considered tainted.
4 --> Modification of global data is forbidden.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to figure out a similar problem. I want to use some gems like json and rest-client inside my sandbox after activating it. I tried following.

```
require "sandbox"
s=Sandbox.safe

s.eval <<-RUBY
  require 'bundler'
  Bundler.require :sandbox
RUBY

s.activate!
```

Gemfile.rb

```
group :sandbox do
  platforms :jruby do
    gem 'json'
    gem 'rest-client'
  end
end
```

This way, I was able to require gems in my sandbox. But, then there were some gem specific issues with sandbox. For eg, I had to add a method initialize_dup to whitelist for safe.rb in jruby-sandbox. RestClient has some problem with Fake File Sytem ALT_SEPARATOR which I am trying to patch. You can try this approach for RSpec and see if everything goes through.